# Is data sharing only supported between accounts in the same Snowflake region?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

"Data Sharing is only supported between accounts in the same Snowflake region" as per multiple sources I have come across.
However, with dB replication we can replicate dB to other accounts across regions and cloud platforms. These two statements seem to contradict. Can someone please clarify?

Answer (score 0):

> "Data Sharing is only supported between accounts in the same Snowflake region"

This text appears to be from an earlier documentation revision that does not appear to hold true anymore with recent enhancements to SnowflakeDB.

As surmised, data shares are supported [across regions via a replication step](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/secure-data-sharing-across-regions-plaforms.html) per the current documentation.

Answer (score 0):

This is all technically accurate.  Data Sharing only works within a single region.  However, you can replicate your account to another region and then data share from that replicated account within that account's region.  This is also true across cloud platforms.

Comment: Not an account but replicating a database through dB replication is a Snowflake feature that I mentioned.

Comment: Not sure what your comment is getting at.  My answer is explaining how you can use data replication in order to share data across regions.  The statements in the documentation do not contradict each other.

Comment: Hey Mike - I read about dB replication and was not sure if a complete account can be replicated too. Anyway, what I understood from your comment is that data sharing between accounts in different regions or cloud platforms is supported by Snowflake.

Answer (score 0):

was preparing for Snowflake Certification and had similar problem.
But I finally realised that you can share data across region ONLY if REPLICATING.

If you are NOT REPLICATING then sharing the data can be only within the region

Please see link below for more details :)

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/snowflake-data-sharing-limitations-tips-minzhen-yang

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).